# More elegant/efficient way to get the 6 consecutive previous DOM elements in a row?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Assuming I have a JQuery object stored in `$e` obtained through this selector:

```
var $e = $("input[type='text'][value='" + v + "']");
```

`v` represents the `$(this).val()` which I obtain inside an `.each()` iteration but it doesn't actually matter, it can be any numeric value.

I want to create a JQuery set of elements containing `$e`, the DOM element which comes after it, and the 6 DOM elements previous to `$e`.

The function itself works perfectly fine, I'm using this code for each iteration:

```
var $e = $("input[type='text'][value='" + v + "']");
$e = $e.add($e.next());
for (i=0;i<6;i++)
    $e = $e.add($e.prev());
$e.remove();
```

I guess it's a little bit hard to explain, so take a look at this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ult_combo/Lf3xm/1/).

I've wrapped the code above inside an anonymous function bound to the the `Remove line 2` button which will pass a fixed `v` value to my script.

I'm a starter with JQuery and even after taking a good read at [JQuery Selectors page](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) I couldn't find a simpler way to do this. I thought that the `.siblings()`, or more specifically [JQuery('prev ~ siblings')](http://api.jquery.com/next-siblings-selector/) could do it in a simpler way if I could specify the range of the jquery objects array but I couldn't figure out how.

The HTML is generated through a PHP template which I'd rather avoid editing, so I'll accept answers which do not include wrapping the given elements inside a container/wrapper.

Is there any simpler way to select the 6 previous elements of a given JQuery selector without wrapping them inside any container or wrapper?

Comment: Is this something >> http://jsfiddle.net/skram/Lf3xm/6/ << close to what you want?

Comment: the values are different, but I see the `.slice(0, 6)` seems to be what I need to put with the previous siblings().

Comment: It does remove previous 6 sibling including self right? Isn't that is what you want?

Comment: Precisely, just accepted your answer. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `.prevAll` and slice the elements you need. See below,

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/skram/Lf3xm/6/)

```
    var $prevAll = $e.prevAll();
    $e = $e.add($e.next()).add($prevAll.slice(0, 6));
```

**Edit:** Added `$e.add($e.next())` to add next element.

Comment: Just missing the "next" element.

Comment: My question was to simplify the previous elements, and `.prevAll().slice(0, 6)` is just genious! Thank you very much. Exactly what I was looking for, but I couldn't find any reference to either of these methods in JQuery before.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `siblings()` and `slice()`:

```
var $e = $("input:text[value='" + v + "']");    

$e.add( $e.siblings().slice(0, 5) ).add( $e.prev() );
```

Comment: Wouldn't this be the first 5 siblings in DOM order plus the 1 previous?  Or does `siblings` return in some other order?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know that it's any better, but it's another option:

```
    var $siblings = $e.siblings().andSelf();
    var index = $siblings.index($e);

    $siblings.slice(index-6,index+2).remove();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Lf3xm/5/

Comment: Is it supposed to remove self + 1? Your demo it is removing (self+1) ->

Comment: @Vega it is.  "containing $e, the DOM element which comes after it, and the 6 DOM elements previous to $e."  If you notice in his example he has `$e.add($e.next());`.

Comment: I see, that is why OP had `$e.add($e.next());`. I missed that though >.<